# Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in config.ovpn:23: ncp-disable (2.3.2)

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn, cyberghost

I'm trying to set up a CyberGhost VPN on my ASUS RT-AC51U router.

I've followed the tutorials exactly (downloaded config files, uploaded openvpn, ca, crt and key files etc) but it's still not connecting. I'm getting the following error message:

rc_service: httpd 212:notify_rc restart_vpncall

openvpn[624]: Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in config.ovpn:23: ncp-disable (2.3.2)

openvpn[624]: Use --help for more information.

In terms of the OpenVPN file, it reads as follows:

client

remote [removed as I think this is sensitive info but its the server info]

dev tun

proto udp

auth-user-pass

resolv-retry infinite

redirect-gateway def1

persist-key

persist-tun

nobind

cipher AES-256-CBC

ncp-disable

auth SHA256

ping 5

ping-exit 60

ping-timer-rem

explicit-exit-notify 2

script-security 2

remote-cert-tls server

route-delay 5

verb 4

Can anybody help point me in the right direction to finding a solution? I can see it's possibly something to do with the 'ncp-disable' line but I'm not sure where to go from there?

Thanks